# Error serializing column into into data type `Nullable(Date)`

Tags: pandas, dataframe, clickhouse

there.
I'm trying to insert pandas df into clickhouse.

My, table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS employees
(
    code Nullable(String),
    num Nullable(String),
    addresses Nullable(String),
    birthDate Nullable(Date),
    employeeID Int32
)
    ENGINE = ReplicatedReplacingMergeTree()
        ORDER BY employeeID
;
```

If, make version without field addresses, than insert is ok, else insert is fail.

Test data:

```
              code         num addresses   birthDate  employeeID
0             NaN  04132585424        []  1945-08-13         122
1    711704045678  13195677868        []  1978-09-26         223
2    772316567842  07456229250        []  1999-04-12         192
3    711408234502  12740654563        []  1989-11-27         764
4    503612346873  07678960666        []  1965-09-28         954
```

Insert statement:

```
df2['birthDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['birthDate'], format='mixed', errors='coerce')
client.insert_df('employees', df2[['code', 'num', 'addresses', 'birthDate', 'employeeID', ]])
```

Error:

```
Error serializing column `birthDate` into into data type `Nullable(Date)`
...
raise DataError('Unable to create Python array.  This is usually caused by trying to insert None ' +
clickhouse_connect.driver.exceptions.DataError: Unable to create Python array.  This is usually caused by trying to insert None values into a ClickHouse column that is not Nullable
```

Comment: The ClickHouse Date type cannot store dates before 01-01-1970.  Does it work with a Date64 type?

Comment: @GeoffGenzyes, Date32 is work for me, phx)

Comment: Good to hear -- yeah I meant Date32 :)